# Problem with find and replace in R Editor

Tags: r, editor

I am currently using R (RGui; R version 4.2.1). I use 'find' and 'replace' in R Editor a lot. Recently, both will only work for one character. So I can find 'a' but it won't find any instances of 'aaa' even if I know they exist. I'd be really happy if anyone can suggest a solution as it's driving me crazy. Thanks!

Comment: I imagine you tried to uninstall/reinstall R... An option would be to use an IDE, like RStudio. I apologize for the lack of originality of this comment.

Comment: I assume you're referring to the `Rgui` interface. I don't use it regularly (actually, I haven't even tried since 2011), but I just opened it now (R-4.1.2) and it works fine. I don't have 4.2.1 around, but frankly I would be surprised if much in `Rgui` has changed much (if at all) in recent versions. Good luck sleuthing it, as my only other recommendations would be to consider the RStudio IDE or VSCode or some other IDE. (I too apologize for my lack of originality ... it's got to be rather frustrating.)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the comments! At this stage, I really appreciate any attempts to help. I did the obvious (clean install). It actually started spontaneously in the previous version of R. And I really didn't want to go down the RStudio route. I feel like it's such a stupid problem, I can't believe there isn't an obvious answer. I was hoping someone maybe had this problem before as it's hard to imagine it's unique!

Comment: I've not seen it, and the last time I saw somebody using `Rgui` (in _earnest_) was a grad professor; he was quite adept at it, tbh, much more so than I would be comfortable using it, but ... with so many people confusing R with RStudio, I don't think I've seen anything regarding the `Rgui` in quite a long time. I wish you luck, I have no ideas other than uninstall completely, reinstall, and try again.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with R 4.2.1. Rgui did find the two instances of `'aaa'` and replace them by `'a3'`, as I told it to.

Answer (score 1):

This was recently fixed in Rgui for Windows.  I am using "R version 4.2.1 Patched (2022-09-28 r82941 ucrt)" and it works (using ctrl-h or the Edit menu in the Rgui R Editor).

In the *BUG FIXES on Windows* subsection within the section *CHANGES IN R 4.2.1 patched* of https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html it says:

> Find and replace operations work again in the script editor in Rgui on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem - with R 4.2.1 I cannot find and replace using the R editor.  I had to close the script up and do it in .txt.

Comment: I rolled back to 4.2.0 and so far it works fine. I will wait for 4.2.2 and hope its not a persistent problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. R version 4.2.1 on Windows 10. It doesn't find anything I search for, even if I can see it right there on the screen. Not even single-character strings. I was editing a non-R file.